# Jenkins - Is it possible to use two different versions of terraform in a jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, terraform

Currently we are using terraform 11 but we would like to start moving to 12. The idea is to move module by module, which means some modules will be using terraform version 11 and those that can run on 12 will be using version 12.
My question now is that in our Jenkins file, we have a stage which downloads terraform 11 and then different stages then to run terraform, is it possible to download terraform 12 as well and have some stages then use 11 and and others use 12?

```
stage('Download Terraform') {
      steps{
        sh "wget path/terraform/0.11.8/terraform-0.11.8.zip"
        sh "unzip -o terraform-0.11.8.zip"
        sh "rm terraform-0.11.8.zip"
      }
    }

stage('Create .terraformrc') {
      steps {
        sh "echo ~"
        writeFile file: "/home/user/.terraformrc", text: """
        credentials "" {
          token = ""
        }
  """
      }
    }

stage('Enable CloudTrail') {
      steps {
        {code}
        }
    }

stage('Create Automation Lambdas') {
      steps {
        {code}
        }
    }
```

In the above example, i would like the "Enable Cloudtrail" stage to run terraform 12 and the "Create Automation Lambdas" stage to run with terraform 11.....

Comment: This would be really easy with Docker agents if that is an option. Otherwise, it would also be easy to download both versions and specify different ones in different stages. It is your choice here.

Comment: Docker isnt available sadly. But i ll try out the downloading both versions and renaming one to tf12 and when its needed just use that instead. Will provide update as soon as i try it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this (sorry if this is not exactly what you needed):

1. Install [terraform plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/terraform/)
2. In jenkins UI > Global Tools Configuration add multiple terraform installations and name them in a consistent, predictable way:

[image]

3. In you pipeline you can now 'pick' the version to use:

   ```
   pipeline {
      agent { label terraformdevagent }
      environment {
        TF_HOME = tool('terraform-0.14.4')
        PATH = "$TF_HOME:$PATH"
    }}
   ```

You can make an optional parameter and a function that returns the parameter if not null and a hardcoded value if the parameter is null.

This way you can have hundreds of jobs under one TF version and still test in isolation the new version.

It can also let you handle exceptions and not block your rollouts because of a handful of projects that need to be refactored for the new version.

TF_HOME = tool( "${params.newTerraformVersion}?:'terraform-0.14.4'")